# Проблема верстки

Tags: меню, шрифты, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите вариант решения такой вот проблемы:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qj5Zb/. 
Меню, в нем несколько кнопок. Когда кнопка становится активной, шрифт внутри становится жирным. Можно ли побороть то, что сама кнопка становится шире? При переходе по страницам раздражает то, что меню "гуляет" туда-сюда. Спасибо.

Comment: такой вариант не подойдёт???  http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/hTfK4/1/

Comment: ширина не должна быть фиксированной, используется sliding doors

Comment: А если так http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/hTfK4/2/

Comment: каков хитрец! хороший варант. но вопрос не закрыт

Comment: А так http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/Qj5Zb/5/

Comment: @Cone - а чего бы тогда не [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Qj5Zb/6/) ?

Comment: народ, но у вас позиционирование жирной ссылки всё равно ведь на глаз?

Comment: Какой ты придирчивый!!!!)) Уже 2 варианта предложили с Js и силами CSS, все равно не устраивает! Наглаз не наглаз, а смотриться вполне приемлимо!!

Comment: @Cone, да мне, поверь, по сути, всё равно. дизайнёры там намесили, а макет уже согласован.

Answer (score 3):

Я в своё время также голову ломал над этим вопросом. Подбирать различные параметры на глаз, на мой взгляд, не разумно, потому что всё равно найдётся ситуация (браузер, ОС и т.д ), когда текст будет скакать.
Лучше фиксировать элемент по ширине и центрировать в неём текст или в крайнем случае использовать спрайты.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вариант

http://jsfiddle.net/Qj5Zb/2/

Там для активного пункта letter-spacing выставлен в 0
И еще весь элемент li.active сдвинут влево на 1px (подобрано на глаз).

Вариант наверное не самый лучший, но рабочий.